# django development show plugin (DjangoQLSearchMixin) but not in production

Tags: python, django

I have a develop env (local run on windows pycharm terminal with --insecure set) that is working properly with this plugin DjangoQLSearchMixin - I can see it on the search engine.

But for some reason it is not activated on the production admin panel (nginx + ubunto + django).

Django version and plugin are the same.

The code is the same, not sure what went wrong.
Maybe I need to recreate static files ?

Suggestions ?

Comment: python manage.py collectstatic

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by recreating the statis css files
python manage.py collectstatic

Thanks.